# Ranking duplicate values with a different number

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose I have a table containing names & numbers.

If there's 2 rows with the exact same values, it will get the same rank.

How can I give them a different number, despite being the same value?

So for example instead of having my ranks like this - 1,2,3,3,4 (where items 3 & 4 have the same rank), I want my rank to look like this - 1,2,3,4,5

**Edit**-

Showing the row number doesn't help me, because as I said I want to rank the rows.

**Example** -

If I use the regular rank, this is what I'll get. What I want is that for User1 with the value 80, it'll show the rank of 2 and 3, not 2 & 2. Same for User2.
Using row number obviously won't give me that result....

```
╔═══════╦═══════╦══════╗
║ Name  ║ Value ║ Rank ║
╠═══════╬═══════╬══════╣
║ User1 ║    90 ║    1 ║
║ User1 ║    80 ║    2 ║
║ User1 ║    80 ║    2 ║
║ User1 ║    70 ║    3 ║
║ User2 ║   100 ║    1 ║
║ User2 ║    90 ║    2 ║
║ User3 ║    90 ║    2 ║
║ User3 ║    80 ║    3 ║
╚═══════╩═══════╩══════╝
```

Hope that was clear enough... Thanks!

Comment: What RDBMS are you using ?

Comment: could you provide some sole code. Also.which rdms are you using?

Comment: if you have two rows with the _exact same values_  then the duplicate rows can be removed and the resulting table is valid by definition. However, if they are 'ordered' then the 'rows' are _not_ the same as the 'position (index)' is part of the 'row values'. so they can be ranked.

Comment: Use `ROW_NUMBER` instead of `RANK`

Comment: @dnoeth please see edit... Row number doesn't help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you say `ROW_NUMBER()` doesn't help you here.

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(Name VARCHAR(10), Value INT)

INSERT @tbl
    SELECT 'User1' ,    90 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'User1' ,    80 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'User1' ,    80 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'User1' ,    70 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'User2' ,   100 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'User2' ,    90 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'User3' ,    90 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'User3' ,    80

SELECT  Name, Value
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Name, Value) AS Rn
FROM @tbl

Name    Value   Rn
User1   70      1
User1   80      2
User1   80      3
User1   90      4
User2   90      1
User2   100     2
User3   80      1
User3   90      2
```

Comment: Please look at your results and the desired results posted in my OP. In your example user2 begins his rank from 5, I want  it to begin from 1

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your RMDBS:

1. SQL Server: use ROW_NUMBER(). This one is ANSI standard.
2. ROWNUM.
3. This feature does not exist: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2014/03/08/mysql-generating-row-number-for-each-row-using-variable/

The query would look like:

```
SELECT FIELD_1, FIELD_2, ROW_NUMBER() FROM TABLE_A
```

Hope that helps

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER()` is ANSI standard and supported by all real databases.